# why cannot declare throw exception class?

Tags: java

```
package com.csl.bps.util;

import java.awt.Event;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.HashMap;

import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;

public class Reloader implements Runnable{
    private boolean firstLoad = true;
    private ServletContextEvent eventCopy = null;
    private File configFile = null;
    private String configFilePath = null;
    private HashMap map = null;
    private BufferedReader reader = null;
    private long lastModifiedTime = 0;
    public Reloader(ServletContextEvent event) {
        eventCopy = event;
        //event.getServletContext().setAttribute("i", new Integer(2));
    }

    public void run() {
        configFilePath = (String)eventCopy.getServletContext().getInitParameter("billRunDetailConfig");
        if(configFilePath == null)
        {
            eventCopy.getServletContext().log("Warning: No bill run detail config file found. Please check the file and restart.");
        }
        configFile = new File(configFilePath);
        if(firstLoad == true)
        {
            map = createMap(configFile);
            lastModifiedTime = configFile.lastModified();
            eventCopy.getServletContext().setAttribute("BunRunDetail", map);
            eventCopy.getServletContext().log("\n\nFirst load of bill run detail config file. HashMap loaded.\n");
            firstLoad = false;
        }
        else
        {
            eventCopy.getServletContext().log("\n\nAnother load of bill run detail config file. Checking for the file's last modified time...\n");
            if(configFile.lastModified() != lastModifiedTime)
            {
                map = createMap(configFile);
                lastModifiedTime = configFile.lastModified();
                eventCopy.getServletContext().setAttribute("BunRunDetail", map);
                eventCopy.getServletContext().log("Config file changed. HashMap is hashed again.");
            }else
            {   
                eventCopy.getServletContext().log("Config file is not changed.");
            }
        }
    }

    private HashMap createMap(File configFile){
        HashMap map = null;
        try{
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(configFile));
        }catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return map;
    }
}
```

I would like throw any exception to the caller of any method, but I cannot, for example:
I can do this:

```
private HashMap createMap(File configFile) throws FileNotFoundException{
    HashMap map = null;
    try{
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(configFile));
    }catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
        //ex.printStackTrace();
        throw ex;
    }
    return map;
}
```

But in the above:

```
if(firstLoad == true)
{
    map = createMap(configFile);
    lastModifiedTime = configFile.lastModified();
    eventCopy.getServletContext().setAttribute("BunRunDetail", map);
    eventCopy.getServletContext().log("\n\nFirst load of bill run detail config file. HashMap loaded.\n");
    firstLoad = false;
}
```

Here in the line of `map = createMap(configFile)` I got a prompt error in eclipse for a not handled exception, but I can only add a try catch clause to it.

I would like it to throw the exception to its caller, and let the caller handle the exception, because if I return in here, I am not sure if all of the resource are close.

---

**Why does its signature doesn't contain a throws clause? Does it assumeit won't produce any exception?**

**If an exception appear, and I wrap it with a try/catch clause, will the thread stop and notify the parent?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you can't add a "throws" clause to the run() method is because run() is defined in the Runnable interface, and its signature does not contain a throws clause.

Comment: I know that, but why does its signature doesn't contain a throws clause? Does it assumeit won't produce any exception?

Comment: Runnable is a very generic interface; any checked exceptions it might throw are too numerous to list (since you can put anything in it,) so it just lists none, and expects that run() will handle checked exceptions, and possibly throw unchecked exceptions and errors.

Answer (score 1):

When you override a method, implement an interface method or implement abstract method, you override it with a method with the **exact** signature which includes the name, the parameter types and order, the throws (**EDIT** as pointed by maaartinus, this relevant only for checked exceptions)(if exists) and the return type. If you want to implement a Runnable you have to implement the method `run` of the `Runnable` interface. The signature of this method does not include any `throw` so you don't override it with your method.

Moreover, while you can declare two methods with the same name but with different arguments, such as:

```
public int foo(int i);
```

and

```
public int foo(String s);
```

You cannot declare two methods with the same name and parameters that differs only in what they throw (**EDIT** as pointed by maaartinus, this relevant only for checked exceptions) or what they return. for example you can't declare two of the three methods at the same time:

```
public int foo();
public boolean foo();
public boolean foo() throws FileNotFoundException;
```

<strike>public boolean foo() throws FileNotFoundException;</strike>

Since you implement `Runnable` you have to implement `public void run()` and you can't implement `public void run() throws FileNotFoundException`.

Comment: Actually, you're quite wrong. When implementing `Closeable` you may implement either `void close() throws IOException` or just `void close()`. Even `void close() throws NullPointerException` is fine. **You just mustn't add any checked exceptions, that's all.**

Answer (score 1):

You mustn't add any checked exceptions to the declaration. The reason is simply that the interface Runnable by not declaring the exception *promises* it won't be thrown by any Runnable.

> I would like it to throw the exception to its caller, and let the caller handle the exception, because if I return in here, I am not sure if all of the resource are close.

You need to catch the exception, but you may throw another unchecked one instead.

```
try {
    ...
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    throw new MyRuntimeFileNotFoundException(e);
}
```

This way you risk forgetting to catch it later (since it's not declared). But sometimes you need this. Of course, you can use simply `throw new RuntimeException(e)` instead of your own.

Comment: +1 for being (much much) more accurate. though I still have doubts about the necessity of catching exception from `run` in most cases.

Comment: @MByD Agreed, in most cases you don't need it. Once I had to wrap one Runnable in another one and catch the exception, so I could log it and perform some clean up. Maybe it could be done differently.

Comment: I don't understand......If I cannot add a throw declaration to it, how can I throw it? And if I cannot throw it, do we have a way to let the caller know "something wrong happened"?

Comment: Wooo, I can wrap the exception in a runtime exception? That's much more convenient.

Comment: Indeed, it's called [exception wrapping](http://www.google.com/search?q=exception+wrapping+java) or [chaining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_chaining).